# Converting XML to JSON and uploading to DB

Tags: mysql, xml, json, node.js, angularjs

I have a frontend app working with AngularJS. For the backend part, I plan to use the data dumps from an external API. These files span from 20MB to 3GB, and they are provided in xml.gz format.

My question is regarding the middle point between having these files and uploading them to a database. The idea is to have a database and to access it using REST from the frontend. 
I'm considering node.js with a mysql module for the backend, but I don't really know what to to with the data files.

So, if I want the database to answer with json responses, do I have to convert the files to json before uploading them to the db? Or it doesn't matter?

Total n00by question, I know, but I'm kinda lost in the whole backend world.

Thanks!

Comment: You have lots of choices! A simple approach would be to use Mongo and just store the json files as "documents". If you want to use MySQL you can either store the data as blobs/text (and use MySQL like a key-value store), or you can create real db tables, in which case you will need some middleware (with node) to convert your table data to json.

Comment: So really I could just upload the xml to tables, and use node to convert the tables to json on "the way down"?

Comment: Yeah, and this is not uncommon or anything, lots of Java backend systems do exactly that by reading db tables and converting to json on output with something like the jackson mapper.

Comment: Thanks @aet! I'll have to dive into the files first to see how they are structured (one file is artists, the other releases, and they are supposed to be linked somehow), but I'll probably follow that path!